# Webkit not working in Chrome after last update in Gen 20024

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

Webkit not working on the scrollbar anymore in chrome, still working in Firefox and other.
Why no one is talking about that, it broke some production css in our application!

If someone has a solution, please help

I tryed to check if it still works in other browser and it does

The CSS code:

```
.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.019);
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}

.scrollbar-primary:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.018);
    background-color: var(--scrollbar-color);
    transition: background-color 0.8s;
}
```

In the last version of Chrome the style is not applied and I have this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

Hope those information can help

Comment: @Paulie_D i added some more information, hope this is ok now

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D the problem is really simple, why i have to create a super complex question where I can put the minimum amount of code and some example to show.
This is a problem that everyone is going to get in production, webkit is not working, those properties are not working and the example is really simple.
If you use webkit to change the scrollbar you have already this problem :)

Comment: No one is asking for a "super complex question" just a [mcve] to **prove** there is a problem. It's highly unlikely that "webkit is not working" completely since it's the foundation of Chrome. You allege that these properties aren't working but you won't prove it... that's all we want you to do.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VwRyBoG?editors=1100

Comment: @Paulie_D your exaple is working perfectly, somehow the same code is not working in production of our application, but working perfectly in Firefox.

My colleague had the same problem after she updated the chrome version.
I don't really know what is happening.
I Found this article of google, but I'm not sure if it is related :
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/scrollbar-styling?hl=it

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the question, if you have even a **single one** of those attributes in one of your CSS classes:
scrollbar-color or scrollbar-width will deactivate all the webkit elements all over the application.

This was a problem caused in the last Chrome update, you can see a post here:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/scrollbar-styling?hl=it

Or read some of the similar post that helped me finding a solution:

https://syntackle.com/blog/changes-to-scrollbar-styling-in-chrome-121/